# Java type mismatch, cannot convert to return itself as the generic type

Tags: java, class, templates, generics, types

It error's on the "return this;" line with this: Type mismatch: cannot convert from A to T.

```
public class A<T extends A<T>>{
    public T method() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the compiler can't convert from A to T, when A is a suitable candidate for T.

Comment: java's "generics". Hilarious.

Comment: Why not just have the return type of `method()` be `A`?

Comment: It really should return `A<T>`, or you'll get a warning that you're trying to return a raw type, and that references to the generic type should be parameterized.

Comment: `A` does not extend `T`, it has a *type parameter* of `T`, so of course you cannot return `this` from `method()`.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Describe your use-case, do you really need [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)?

Comment: Let's say there's a public class B extends A<B> {...}. I then would like to be able to call B.method().otherBMethods(), without having to override A's method() in B. This is for the benefit of a Builder Design Pattern that's using inheritance as much as the classes that it's building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Let us assume your code was valid...**

You might have a subclass defined like this

```
public class B extends A<B> {

}
```

Here type parameter `T` is same as type of `this`.
Which is why I guess you said

> A is a suitable candidate for T

---

Now consider this case

```
public class C extends A<B> {

}
```

which is perfectly valid since `B` passes all criteria required for `T`.

In this case your method declaration in class `A` becomes invalid.
(return type is `B` but you are returning instance of class `C`.)

---

So your assumption that

> A is a suitable candidate for T

is invalid. Hence the error.

Hope this helps.
Good luck.